# Runtime error from a project i cloned from GitHub

Tags: android, flutter

I cloned a project from Github to see how it works on my emulator at runtime I got this error

This app is using a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures or future build failures, try to migrate this app to the V2 embedding.

how do I resolve these issues

Comment: The project you cloned is too old. You need to migrate it to v2 embedding for it to work with latest flutter versions.

Answer (score 0):

The error should provide a link with migration guide, the simplest way is to move the code files into newly created flutter project.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to make it easy.

try deleting the android folder in your project folder, then run 'flutter create .' on terminal from your project root to recreate the new android folder.
(but this may fail sometimes so better keep a copy of your android folder)